# php report-Strict Standards: mktime(): You should be using the time() function instead

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP report that is using a date variable to return results from the MySQL database.

I did not write the report an it uses `mktime` and I have recently moved to a new server with the latest version of php and i now get

This the date variable creation:

```
$start_date  = mktime(0,0,0,$StartMonth,$StartDay,$StartYear);
$end_date    = mktime(23,59,59,$EndMonth,$EndDay,$EndYear);
```

And later to get the date:

```
if ($HTTP_SERVER_VARS['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    if ($prefix == "Start") {
            $currYear = $StartYear;
            $currMonth = $StartMonth;
            $currDay = $StartDay;
    }
    elseif ($prefix == "End") {
            $currYear = $EndYear;
            $currMonth = $EndMonth;
            $currDay = $EndDay;
    }
}
else {
    $arr = getdate(mktime());
    $currYear = $arr["year"];
    $currMonth = $arr["mon"];

    // If the user hasn't chosen a date, 
    // set the beginning day at the first of the month
    if ($prefix == "Start")
            $currDay = 01;
    else
            $currDay = $arr["mday"];
}
```

When I run the report now I get `Strict Standards: mktime(): You should be using the time() function instead`

I have changed it to `$arr = getdate(time());` and it gets rid of the error but now the date picker does not work.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php says:
As of PHP 5.1, when called with no arguments, mktime() throws an E_STRICT notice: use the time() function instead.

Comment: You can try using `print_r(getdate(mktime()))` and `print_r(getdate(time()))` to check if there are differences that could throw off the date picker.

Comment: I'm not seeing how `$start_date` and `$end_date` are used.  Is your problem just with the `$arr = getdate(mktime());` line (and a subsequent date picker)?  Could you reduce your code to just that?

Comment: The problem is with $arr = getdate(mktime());   If i change it to say time() it doesnt work.  I will get rid of that array to get date and try to do it with just the date picker

Comment: Can you post the code for how you declare $arr.

Answer (score 5):

Calling `mktime()` with no parameters is the same as calling `time()`. The function declaration looks like this:

```
int mktime ([ int $hour = date("H") [, int $minute = date("i") [, int $second = date("s") [, int $month = date("n") [, int $day = date("j") [, int $year = date("Y") [, int $is_dst = -1 ]]]]]]] )
```

In other words, using no parameters is the same as using the current date, which is what `time()` does.

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > echo mktime();

Strict Standards: mktime(): You should be using the time() function instead in php shell code on line 1
1450208188
php > echo time();
1450208189
php >
```

Nothing has broken because you changed `mktime()` to `time()`. There's something else going on.